# How do I debug drawing on Canvas in onDraw method?

Tags: android

I'm implementing my custom View where I override `onDraw()` method in order to draw some set of objects.

The objects are supposed to be placed in a coordinates which are evaluated in a particular way. The code placing those objects works incorrectly (some of them are either not drawn at all or are overlayed by other objects) so that I need to do some debugging to execute it line-by-line and watch what is actually being drawn step-by-step.

However as far as I understand the actual picture is shown on the screen after all the drawing is completed since when I'm executing `canvas.drawBitmap` line nothing is appearing on my emulator's screen.

My question is: What is the best (or maybe the only) way to debug `onDraw()` code? I did some research in Adroid dev portal and here in posted questions but was unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but it should put you on the right track:

- At the start of your onDraw method, make a new Bitmap using the width and height from the canvas
- Make a new Canvas from the Bitmap
- Run your draw calls on this Canvas
- You can inspect the Bitmap from the Android Studio debugger, and will update with every draw call
- If you also want to draw the data to the screen, you can use drawBitmap on the original Canvas with your full Bitmap, but this shouldn't be needed for debugging

**Don't leave this in production code**

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap screenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas screenCanvas = new Canvas(screenBitmap);

   /* Run draw calls on screenCanvas, inspect screenBitmap for result*/
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to "watch what is actually being drawn step-by-step". To make it clear, when you debug in Android Studio, and inspect a Bitmap (by Run > Evaluate Expression, or in the Variables view), to the right of the variable, a "View Bitmap" label / button appears. If you click that, you can actually see the bitmap in any half-drawn state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I know graphics acceleration in nowadays Android is quite complex: drawing commands are recorded in drawing lists, which are then optimized and handled to the GPU to be drawn. And, since Android 5.0, part of the drawing that needs to be handled in the CPU can (is always?) run in a background thread. See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/ for general background.

Then, about the tools, I would suggest using `systrace`. For more information and a detailed example on how to use it and more tools, see the excellent (albeit probably a bit outdated) article by Romain Guy "[Android Performance Case Study](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/)" and the follow-up "[Android Performance Case Study Follow-up](http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/)".

Also, see Android documentation "[Perfect GPU Use](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/gpu.html)".

Hope this sets you in the right path. This is a very complex subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can try commenting the suspicious statements.

Another option would be to use a timer - Frequently invalidate the view from a different thread and inside `onDraw` run different statements only if some time has elapsed. Use different time for different statements, so that it looks like an animation.